# Conditional Regression Model in Python

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, regression, statsmodels

In python, I have created a regression model by using this code:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": data['dur'], "B": data['agreement'], "C": data['vidPersonIdeoDiff'], "D": data['opinionChange'],  "G": data['fake']})
result = sm.ols(formula="A ~ B + C + D + G", data=df).fit()
print(result.params)

print(result.summary())
```

Now, I am interested in adding a condition or 'if-statement' to the same regression. How would I run it but only for certain groups, such as if age is < 36? In Stata, the equivalent would be:

```
reg dur agreement vidPersonIdeoDiff opinionChange fake if age < 36
```

Any idea how I can replicate that stata line in python? It'd be especially helpful if the solution is congruent to the statsmodels.formula.api module I've been using. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[2,4,6,8,10]})
```

you can select only the rows where value in the 'age' column is greater than 3 like this:

```
age_greater_3 = df[df['age']>3]
```

Then just use age_greater_3 in place of df

Answer (score 1):

If say, 'age' is the variable on which you have condition:

```
result = sm.ols(formula="A ~ B + C + D + G", data=df[data['age']<36]).fit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply subset the data frame...

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': np.random.normal(1000), 'z': np.random.rand(1000) > 0.5}
)
df['y'] = df['x'] * 2 + np.random.normal(1000)

# full dataset
sm.ols(formula='y ~ x', data=df).fit().summary()
# conditional on z = True
sm.ols(formula='y ~ x', data=df.loc[df['z']]).fit().summary()

# for a continuous variable
df['age'] = np.random.randint(18, 65, 1000)
sm.ols(formula='y ~ x', data=df[df['age'] > 30]).fit().summary()
```